# Why can't I remove current observation using .I in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Recently I saw a question (can't find the link) that was something like this

> I want to add a column on a data.frame that computes the variance of a different column while removing the current observation.

```
dt = data.table(
  id = c(1:13),
  v = c(9,5,8,1,25,14,7,87,98,63,32,12,15)
)
```

So, with a `for()` loop:

```
res = NULL
for(i in 1:13){
  res[i] = var(dt[-i,v])
}
```

I tried doing this in data.table, using negative indexing with `.I`, but to my surprise none of the following works:

```
#1
dt[,var := var(dt[,v][-.I])]

#2
dt[,var := var(dt$v[-.I])]

#3 
fun = function(x){
  v = c(9,5,8,1,25,14,7,87,98,63,32,12,15)
  var(v[-x])
}
dt[,var := fun(.I)]

#4
fun = function(x){
  var(dt[-x,v])
}
dt[,var := fun(.I)]
```

All of those gives the same output:

```
    id  v var
 1:  1  9  NA
 2:  2  5  NA
 3:  3  8  NA
 4:  4  1  NA
 5:  5 25  NA
 6:  6 14  NA
 7:  7  7  NA
 8:  8 87  NA
 9:  9 98  NA
10: 10 63  NA
11: 11 32  NA
12: 12 12  NA
13: 13 15  NA
```

What am I missing? I thought it was a problem with `.I` being passed to functions, but a dummy example:

```
fun = function(x,c){
  x*c
}
dt[,dummy := fun(.I,2)]

    id  v var
 1:  1  9   2
 2:  2  5   4
 3:  3  8   6
 4:  4  1   8
 5:  5 25  10
 6:  6 14  12
 7:  7  7  14
 8:  8 87  16
 9:  9 98  18
10: 10 63  20
11: 11 32  22
12: 12 12  24
13: 13 15  26
```

works fine.

Why can't I use `.I` in this specific scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `.BY`:

> a `list` containing a length 1 vector for each item in `by`

```
dt[ , var_v := dt[id != .BY$id,  var(v)], by = id]
```

Variance is calculated once per row (`by = id`). In each calculation, the current row is excluded using `id != .BY$id` in the 'inner' `i`.

```
all.equal(dt$var_v, res)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Why doesn't your code work? Because...

> `.I` is an integer vector equal to `seq_len(nrow(x))`,

...your `-.I` not only removes *current* observation, it removes *all* rows in one go from 'v'.

A small illustration which starts with your attempt (just without the assignment `:=`) and simplifies it step by step:

```
# your attempt
dt[ , var(dt[, v][-.I])]
# [1] NA

# without the `var`, indexing only
dt[ , dt[ , v][-.I]]
# numeric(0)
# an empty vector

# same indexing written in a simpler way
dt[ , v[-.I]]
# numeric(0)

# even more simplified, with a vector of values
# and its corresponding indexes (equivalent to .I)
v <- as.numeric(11:14)
i <- 1:4
v[i]
# [1] 11 12 13 14

x[-i]
# numeric(0)
```

Comment: Nice use without my external function. The dot-capitalized commands in `data.table` come in handy when you know they exist and know how to use them. Thanks!

Comment: Nice indeed. But also, do you guys know why the `.I` approach doesn't work?

Comment: @Fino I added some explanation. Please let me know if it makes sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brute-force thought:

```r
exvar <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) sapply(seq_len(length(x)), function(i) var(x[-i], na.rm = na.rm))
dt[,var := exvar(v)]
dt
#     id  v      var
#  1:  1  9 1115.538
#  2:  2  5 1098.265
#  3:  3  8 1111.515
#  4:  4  1 1077.841
#  5:  5 25 1153.114
#  6:  6 14 1132.697
#  7:  7  7 1107.295
#  8:  8 87  822.447
#  9:  9 98  684.697
# 10: 10 63 1040.265
# 11: 11 32 1153.697
# 12: 12 12 1126.424
# 13: 13 15 1135.538
```